# mysql select unique values from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have data that looks like this:

```
table:master
topic| subtopic |  task  
recreation | skiiing  | use poles
recreation | skiiing  | wax skiis
events  | block party | run electricity
events  | skiing | purchase banner
```

I moved the data into a relational mysql database so it looks like this

```
table: topics
id | name
1 | recreation
2 | events
----------------------
table : subtopics
id | name | topic
1 | skiing | 1
2 | block party | 2
3 | skiing | 2
```

I'm having a hard time grabbing tasks without repeating them in the tasks table.

My current statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TASKS
SELECT
 master.task,
 subtopics.id
FROM master,subtopics
WHERE master.subtopic = subtopic.name
AND master.topic = topic.name
```

When I run it, the result gives me 2 instances of 'use poles', one pointing to subtopic 1, the other to subtopic 3 - which is incorrect.

How can I run the SELECT statement to only pull the task that is unique to the topic/subtopic combination?

Comment: select `distinct` perhaps. Also please migrate toward explicit joins. What that means is that your `where` clause performs the join. It is not a source of the problem, it is just that we don't code like that anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join all three tables (topic doesn't appear in the FROM clause of your query but does in the WHERE clause).

```
INSERT INTO TASKS
SELECT master.task, subtopics.id
FROM master
JOIN topic ON master.topic = topic.name
JOIN subtopics ON master.subtopic = subtopics.name AND subtopics.topic = topic.id
```

Comment: without testing it, this would seem to do the trick and uses explicit joins. nice answer Paul

Comment: I find the explicit JOIN syntax does make it easy to spot missing join conditions. I know other people may not like it, but rather than using field names like 'id' and 'topic' I prefer 'pkTopics' and 'fkTopics' - so it is clear that you are joining the correct fields (_subtopics.fkTopic = topics.pkTopics)_

Comment: it is the new century afterall. `where` is a filter. we have so moved passed `where` for a join

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much.  It's really appreciated!